# Calculating mean of full pixels within a box in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcgis-pro, statistics, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean of pixels within a boundary.

I am able to find the mean using the calculate Statistics and Zonal Statistics as a table GP tool in ArcMap.

But, the issue is I would like to get the mean of entire pixels participating in the boundary and ignore the intersecting pixels.

*Like in the screenshot below I would like to get the mean of only 6 pixels which are entirely within the box.*

**Input:**
[image]

**Output Table:**

[image]

I have a workaround of redrawing the box to exactly include the required pixels, and also use the pixel inspector to get the pixel values then copy the values to Excel and find mean there.

The workaround is not optimum, as there are multiple other boundaries and rasters to work with.

I am using ArcMap.

Comment: Feel free to ask about using ArcGIS Pro or Python (with a code attempt) in separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

Workflow:

1. Convert polygon to raster, ensure cell size is the same size as the raster and snap to raster is set.
2. Run shrink tool, shrinking by 1 pixel to create mask.
3. Run zonal statistics tool using newly created mask.

[image: Example]

This could all be very easily wrapped up in a model if you need to automate it.

Comment: What if all pixels are completely inside the box:)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Are you asking what if the polygon is exactly 5x4 pixels and aligned to the raster? If so, the logic holds and the shrink tool would return a 2x3 raster, what would be the blue raster above which can be  used in the zonal stats tool.

Comment: Yes, but statistics will be different.